# APK Compatibility issue for 7 and 10 inch tablets.

Tags: android, google-play, apk, compatibility, publish

I have published my APK on google play store, Once I uploaded new APK it suggests that APK is not compatible for 7 inch and 10 inch tables.

I have added "layout-sw600dp" and "layout-sw720dp" folders and removed "layout-large" and "layout-xlarge" folders, and then uploaded the APK again still showing the same.

My Application is not designed as "Multipan" application still I want to make it compatible with 7 inch and 10 inch tablets.

How can I do it? Please suggest, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: nice question but i can't know about this.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to support all screens you have to have these lines in your AndroidManifest:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true">
</supports-screens>

<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Special case for new phones with large screens 5"+ and Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Answer (score 0):

add in your manifest file

> **supports-screens 
>       android:smallScreens="true"
>       android:normalScreens="true" 
>       android:largeScreens="true"
>       android:xlargeScreens = "true"
>       android:anyDensity="true" />**